# Call edit method from a main class in X++

Tags: x++, dynamics-365-operations

I want to recall a value of an `edit` method declared inside a form from a class main. How can I do it?

```
[Form]
public class AdvancedCustomerSchedule extends FormRun
{        
    Sorting sorting;    

    edit Sorting edtSorting(boolean set, Sorting _sorting)
    {
        if (set)
        {
            sorting = _sorting;
        }
        return sorting;
    }
 }
```

and the class:

```
class AdvancedCustomerScheduleService 
{
  static void main(Args args)
  {
       //I want to call the method edtSorting here.
  }
}
```

**UPDATE**

```
FormRun callerForm;
if (args.caller() is FormRun)
        {
            callerForm = args.caller() as FormRun;

            if (formHasMethod(callerForm, identifierStr(edtSorting)))
            {
                str test  = callerForm.edtSorting();
                info(test);
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For calling methods defined on forms in general you usually use a pattern like the following:

```
...
FormRun callerForm;
...
if (_args.caller() is FormRun)
{
    callerForm = _args.caller();

    if (formHasMethod(callerForm, identifierStr(someMethod)))
    {
        callerForm.someMethod();
    }
    ...
```

Have a look at class `DirPartyContactInfoFormHandler` and its static `main` method for an example.

Comment: when i try to call the method with `callerForm.edtSorting();` i catch an exception: it can't find the method. Any help?

Comment: Did you provide all required parameters?

Comment: any suggestions?

Comment: Again, it looks like you don't pass any arguments  to a method which takes two parameters.

Comment: Sorry, i forgot it :D